# dojo Expando pane content goes hidden when expanded

Tags: dojo, splitter, expando

I have expandoPane which consists of some buttons.
When I perform other operations in the project and then expand this expandoPane, its contents goes hidden and those are visble after resizing it using splitter only.

I want to solve this.
Do you have any idea why the content goes invisible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .startup and .resize() on the content pane when it's shown.

Something like:

```
expandoPane.connect(this, "onClick", function() {
    that.createContent();
    that.startup();
    that.container.resize()
});
```

Post your code and I'll probably be able to give you something more specific.

Comment: I have already posted the code for the expando pane containing button and contentpane.In my layout I have bordercontainer with splitter.I tried startup and resize methods, still I need to resize splitter manually to make those visible.

Answer (score 0):

Adding sample code:

```
  <div id="expandableConsole" dojoType="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane" region="bottom"  showTitle='true' maxHeight="250px" maxWidth="280px" style="height:200px; width:100%;" doLayout='true' startExpanded='false' splitter="true"> 
     <div>
          <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" style="width:88px;height:20px" onclick="update()"> 
     </div>         
     <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="infoBar" style="height:150px">
     </div>                     
  </div>
```

When I expand the expandopane after few operations,button and contentpane go invisible.